# Об употреблении слов "либо" и "не"

Tags: семантика

Предположим на столике лежат туз и король.

Верно ли, что:

- указание "Не бери туза либо короля." означает указание "Либо возьми туза, либо не бери короля.",
- указание "Либо возьми туза, либо не бери короля." означает указание "Либо не бери туза, либо возьми короля."?

Answer (score 1):

1. Неверно. Императив "**не бери**" предоставляет выбор - не брать туза или не брать короля. Исполнитель имеет следующие возможности:

а) не взять короля, взяв туза;

б) не взять туза, взяв короля;

в) не взять ни короля, ни туза (поскольку указание не содержит посыла нечто взять, а только "не брать").

Указание, таким образом, сводится к запрету брать обе карты. Интересно, что инвертирование самого императива исключит возможность в):
 "**Возьми** короля либо туза" будет означать запрет брать обе карты и запрет не брать ни одной карты.

Указание "Либо возьми туза, либо не бери короля" предоставляет исполнителю на выбор возможности

а) взять и туза и короля;

б) не брать короля, не взяв и туза.

Указание, таким образом, сводится к запрету брать только одну карту

---

2. Верно. Оба указания сводятся (см. выше) к запрету брать только одну карту.

---

Задачка, замечу, не по употреблению союзов, а по булевой алгебре... как, видимо, и прочие вопросы той же серии.

Comment: Если это не задача на булеву логику -- тогда лучше писать простым языком, чтобы правила были просты и понятны.